# Установка Visual Studio на внешний жесткий диск

Tags: visual-studio

Всем привет!
Если на внешнем жестком диске установлена отдельная операционка, можно ли установить туда Visual Studio. Будет ли корректно работать? При загрузке ноутбука, естественно буду выбирать ту ОС, что на внешнем установлена.

Comment: Если у вас есть ОС на этом диске и достаточно места для установки, то почему бы и нет?

Comment: Можно. Мы разрешаем)

Comment: Ну если разрешаете, то попробую! Позже отпишусь здесь о результатах